# How to mock dynamodb promise support using jest?

Tags: javascript, express, jestjs, amazon-dynamodb

There are [similar questions but all of them uses some kind of library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42443655/mocking-using-aws-sdk-mocks-promise-support-with-documentclient) ( which does not work in my case).How do i make i work for promise return by dynamodb query

here is my code to be tested

```
  const isUrl = require('is-url');
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const { nanoid } = require('nanoid/async');
const express = require('express');

const router = express.Router();
const dynamoDb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

// URL from users

router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
  // urlId contains converted short url characters generated by nanoid

  const urlId = await nanoid(8);
  const { longUrl } = req.body;

  // Veryfying url Format using isUrl, this return a boolean
  const checkUrl = isUrl(longUrl);
  if (checkUrl === false) {
    return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Invalid URL, please try again!!!' });
  }

  const originalUrl = longUrl;
  const userType = 'anonymous'; // user type for anonymous users
  const tableName = 'table-name'; // table name for storing url's

  const anonymousUrlCheckParams = {
    TableName: tableName,
    Key: {
      userId: userType,
      originalUrl,
    },
  };

  const paramsForTransaction = {
    TransactItems: [
      {
        Put: {
          TableName: tableName,
          Item: {
            userId: userType,
            originalUrl,
            convertedUrl: `https://url/${urlId}`,
          },
        },
      },

      {
        Put: {
          TableName: tableName,
          Item: {
            userId: urlId,
            originalUrl,
          },
          ConditionExpression: 'attribute_not_exists(userId)',
        },
      },
    ],
  };

  try {
    const dynamoDbGetResults = await dynamoDb
      .get(anonymousUrlCheckParams)
      .promise();
    if (
      Object.keys(dynamoDbGetResults).length === 0 &&
      dynamoDbGetResults.constructor === Object
    ) {
      await dynamoDb.transactWrite(paramsForTransaction).promise();
      return res.status(201).json({
        convertedUrl: `https://trimify.awssensei.tk/${urlId}`,
      });
    }
    return res.status(201).json({
      convertedUrl: dynamoDbGetResults.Item.convertedUrl,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    return res
      .status(500)
      .json({ error: 'Unknown Server Error, Please Trimify Again!' });
  }
});
```

module.exports = router;

my test code

```
describe('Test for Authenticated Url', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.resetModules();
  });
  test('should return converted url for authenticated user', async () => {
    const mockedDocumentClient = {
      get: jest.fn(),
      transactWrite: jest.fn(),
    };

    const mockedDynamoDB = {
      DocumentClient: jest.fn(() => mockedDocumentClient),
    };
    jest.doMock('aws-sdk', () => ({ DynamoDB: mockedDynamoDB }));

    mockedDocumentClient.get.mockImplementation((params, callback) => {
      const data = {
        Item: {
          convertedUrl: 'xyz',
        },
      };
      callback(null, data);
    });
    mockedDocumentClient.transactWrite.mockImplementation(
      (params, callback) => {
        callback(null);
      }
    );

    const app = require('../app');
    const response = await request(app).post('/auth-ops/convert').send({
      longUrl: 'https://google.com',
      userId: 'google-oauth2|110198332436292901252',
    });
    expect(response.body).toMatchObject({ convertedUrl: 'xyz' });
    expect(response.statusCode).toBe(201);
  });
test('should send 201 when it is new Url', async () => {
    const mockedDocumentClient = {
      get: jest.fn(),
      transactWrite: jest.fn(),
    };

    const mockedDynamoDB = {
      DocumentClient: jest.fn(() => mockedDocumentClient),
    };
    jest.doMock('aws-sdk', () => ({ DynamoDB: mockedDynamoDB }));

    mockedDocumentClient.get.mockImplementation((params, callback) => {
      const data = {};
      callback(null, data);
    });
    mockedDocumentClient.transactWrite.mockImplementation(
      (params, callback) => {
        callback(null);
      }
    );

    const app = require('../app');
    const response = await request(app).post('/auth-ops/convert').send({
      longUrl: 'https://google.com',
      userId: 'google-oauth2|110198332436292901252',
    });
    expect(response.body).not.toBe(undefined);
    expect(response.statusCode).toBe(201);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

i removed the express specific code and create an example using your logic, i added 3 comments, "CASE A", "CASE B" and "CASE C", which co-relates to all branches in your code (e.g. ifs or returns), we will use that in our test case

```js
let AWS = require("aws-sdk");

let dynamoDb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({ apiVersion: "2012-08-10" });

async function main() {
  try {
    const dynamoDbGetResults = await dynamoDb.get("some-loginUrlCheckParams").promise();
    // CASE A
    if (Object.keys(dynamoDbGetResults).length === 0 && dynamoDbGetResults.constructor === Object) {
      let urlId = await dynamoDb.transactWrite("some-paramsForTransaction").promise();
      return {
        convertedUrl: `https://my-url/${urlId}`,
      };
    }
    // CASE B
    return {
      convertedUrl: dynamoDbGetResults.Item.convertedUrl,
    };
  } catch (err) {
    // CASE C
    return { error: "Unknown Server Error, Please Trimify Again!", message: err.message };
  }
}

module.exports = { main };
```

from here, we would need to have access to `.get` and `.transactWrite` per test, so we can mock the values returned in that specific case

to achieve that, you can take advantage of how jest mock and hoist variables starting with `mock*` works

creating an api to manipulate the returned value per test case:

```js
let AWS = require("aws-sdk");

let { main } = require("./main");

let mockDocumentClient = {
  get: {
    promise: jest.fn()
  },
  transactWrite: {
    promise: jest.fn()
  },
};

jest.mock("aws-sdk", () => {
  return {
    DynamoDB: {
      DocumentClient: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
        return {
          get: () => mockDocumentClient.get,
          transactWrite: () => mockDocumentClient.transactWrite,
        };
      }),
    },
  };
});

describe("Test for Authenticated Url", () => {
  it("returns CASE A", async () => {
    mockDocumentClient.get.promise.mockReturnValueOnce({})
    mockDocumentClient.transactWrite.promise.mockReturnValueOnce("test-urlId")
    let test = await main();
    expect(test).toEqual({ convertedUrl: 'https://my-url/test-urlId' })
  });

  it("returns CASE B", async () => {
    mockDocumentClient.get.promise.mockReturnValueOnce({
      Item: {
        convertedUrl: "test-converted-url"
      }
    })
    let test = await main();
    expect(test).toEqual({ convertedUrl: 'test-converted-url' })
  });

  it("returns CASE C", async () => {
    mockDocumentClient.get.promise.mockImplementationOnce(() => {
      throw new Error("test-error")
    })
    let test = await main();
    expect(test).toEqual({ error: 'Unknown Server Error, Please Trimify Again!', message: "test-error" })
  });
});
```

as you can see, we lazy load `mockDocumentClient` into our `jest.mock` (Jest will only call `mockDocumentClient` when the function of `get: () =>` is executed), enabling us to pass the same mock variable to our test cases and manipulate the returned value

achieving 100% test coverage in that snippet:

[image]

i highly recommend you to review these two articles, they will explain it in more detail from Jest perspective:

https://jestjs.io/docs/es6-class-mocks#calling-jestmock-with-the-module-factory-parameter

https://blog.bam.tech/developer-news/fix-jest-mock-cannot-access-before-initialization-error

Comment: i am sorry i edited my question, and  still new to jest and its mighty mocking can, you explain it again or check my edit

Comment: nothing changes from a test perspective @JatinMehrotra, because the aws-sdk library is still the same, you can follow the mock structure i provided in my answer to achieve what you asked for

Comment: i will try your code. would you take some pains to explain this `let mockDocumentClient = {
  get: {
    promise: jest.fn()
  },
  transactWrite: {
    promise: jest.fn()
  },
};

jest.mock("aws-sdk", () => {
  return {
    DynamoDB: {
      DocumentClient: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
        return {
          get: () => mockDocumentClient.get,
          transactWrite: () => mockDocumentClient.transactWrite,
        };
      }),
    },
  };
});`

Answer (score 0):

you should reproduce dynamodb signature with mock (my example is just general, idk all details of you dynamo import)

```
jest.mock('dynamodb', () => {
  get: async (data) => jest.fn()
})
```

Comment: can  you tell me either with aws-sdlk-mock library or the way i am trying to mock

Comment: @JatinMehrotra you can try stubmatic, please check this article https://amitgupta-gwl.medium.com/mock-dynamodb-services-5192cdcc450f

Comment: or as you say aws-sdk-mock

`
var AWS = require('aws-sdk-mock');
 
AWS.mock('DynamoDB', 'putItem', function (params, callback){
  callback(null, "successfully put item in database");
});
 
/**
    TESTS
**/ 

AWS.restore('DynamoDB');
`